# Error in macro with __va_args__ and parenthesis

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I've downloaded from internet and recompiled a librarian, with the result of a core dump due to illegal pointer address.

Looking at source, the involved statements are:

```
#define E_DEBUG(level, ...) \
    if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
        err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, FILELINE, __VA_ARGS__)
#define E_DEBUGCONT(level, ...) \
    if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
        err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, NULL, 0, __VA_ARGS__)
```

and the line that crashes:

```
E_DEBUGCONT(1, (" %d", i));
```

In fact, the compiler is warning about it:

```
In file included from ptm_mgau.c:56:0:
ptm_mgau.c: In function ‘ptm_mgau_calc_cb_active’:
ptm_mgau.c:317:30: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
         E_DEBUGCONT(1, (" %d", i)); 
                              ^
/home/pma/actual/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/../sphinxbase-5prealpha/include/sphinxbase/err.h:142:37: note: in definition of macro ‘E_DEBUGCONT’

ptm_mgau.c:317:24: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘err_msg’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         E_DEBUGCONT(1, (" %d", i)); 
                        ^
/home/pma/actual/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/../sphinxbase-5prealpha/include/sphinxbase/err.h:142:37: note: in definition of macro ‘E_DEBUGCONT’

/home/pma/actual/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/../sphinxbase-5prealpha/include/sphinxbase/err.h:159:1: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 err_msg(err_lvl_t lvl, const char *path, long ln, const char *fmt, ...);
```

Compiler is very exact in what will happen: in expression `( " %d", i )` means ignore `"%d"` and result in value of `i`. Latter, this i is used as pointer, causing the crash.

It seems the author of the code expect that macro expansion produces the line:

```
if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
    err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, NULL, 0, " %d", i)
```

but preprocessor produces:

```
if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
    err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, NULL, 0, ( " %d", i) )
```

there are any way to resolve the issue, **changing the macro definition** instead of go one by one over all the DEBUG statements (hundreds of them) ?

** Addendum **

A minimal example to reproduce the issue is, compile and execute following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define ERR_DEBUG 1
#define FILELINE  __FILE__ , __LINE__

void err_msg(int lvl, const char *path, long ln, const char *fmt, ...) {

    char msg[1024];

    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    printf("%s\n",msg);

}

#define E_DEBUG(level, ...) \
        err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, FILELINE, __VA_ARGS__)

int main ( void ) {
  E_DEBUG(1,("%d",14));
}
```

Comment: Do all the DEBUG statements have those extra parens?

Comment: It seems so, but I'm not the author

Comment: The best way to fix would be to correct the errorneous code. Write a small script (e.g. in Python) or use sed to remove the parentheses. As a word of warning: If the code fails at such obvious details (the author should have noticed that when compiling himself),I'd be suspicious about the code as such.

Comment: We are talking about one of the most used librarians in speech to text conversion. Hypothesis: this was OK years ago, ¿some change in standard caused the hidden problem produces now a crash? Probably nowadays nobody used it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
#define PASTE(...) __VA_ARGS__

/*PASTE __VA_ARGS__ */
```

will remove the parentheses but it depends on the parentheses being *always* there.

Applied to your example, this:

```
#define PASTE(...) __VA_ARGS__


#define E_DEBUG(level, ...) \
    if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
        err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, FILELINE, PASTE __VA_ARGS__)

#define ERR_DEBUG 1
#define FILELINE  __FILE__ , __LINE__

int err_get_debug_level(void);
void err_msg(int lvl, const char *path, long ln, const char *fmt, ...);


int main ( void ) {
  E_DEBUG(1,("%d",14));
}
```

compiles.

Comment: Now is perfect. Moreover, taken into account that the library compiles, it seems all cases have the parenthesis. Thanks a lot. One additional thing: I suppose this issue caused no problem some time ago, when the library was created. ¿any change in C/C++ standard could cause the issue?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I'm not aware of any old C standard that would allow the parenthesised form to work. I'd also recommend actual editing of the code as Olaf suggest, instead of this macro hack.