# Error in macro with __VA_OPT__ and parenthesis

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

I am using c++,gcc. I have code for logging with macro like this:

```
#define E_DEBUG(level, ...) \
    if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
        err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, FILELINE, __VA_OPT__)

#define ERR_DEBUG 1
#define FILELINE  __FILE__ , __LINE__

int err_get_debug_level(void);
void err_msg(int lvl, const char *path, long ln, const char *fmt, ...);


int main ( void ) {
  E_DEBUG(1,("%d",14));
}
```

The code give an error **VA_OPT** must be followed by an open parenthesis

I change the code according this [Error in macro with __va_args__ and parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032244/error-in-macro-with-va-args-and-parenthesis).
The code look like:

```
#define PASTE(...) __VA_OPT__


#define E_DEBUG(level, ...) \
    if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
        err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, FILELINE, PASTE __VA_OPT__)

#define ERR_DEBUG 1
#define FILELINE  __FILE__ , __LINE__

int err_get_debug_level(void);
void err_msg(int lvl, const char *path, long ln, const char *fmt, ...);


int main ( void ) {
  E_DEBUG(1,("%d",14));
}
```

It gives an error unterminated **VA_OPT**. How should I fix it?

Comment: Why are you wrapping `("%d", 14)` in extra parenthesis? What are you trying to do here? You are also mixing `__VA_OPT__` and `__VA_ARGS__`.

Answer (score 1):

`__VA_OPT__` is used to conditionally insert something in your macro, it's not equivalent to `__VA_ARGS__`, you need both:

```cpp
#define E_DEBUG(level, ...) \
    if (err_get_debug_level() >= level) \
        err_msg(ERR_DEBUG, FILELINE __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

This will not compile with your code because you used `("%d", 14)` and I don't really understand why. If you remove the extra brackets, the code compiles.